# No CiviCRM link in my WordPress menu after migration from Drupal to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I migrated CiviCRM running under Drupal 7 to CiviCRM running under Wordpress due to the lack of automatic updates in Drupal.

I am able to manage CiviCRM from the administrator's backend of Wordpress, but I want to give access to CiviCRM from the front end, as I did under Drupal.

There is a page called CiviCRM but it doesn't display anything else than "Do not delete this page. Page content is generated by CiviCRM", but actually, it is not.

I searched for some shortcode to introduce the whole CiviCRM interface, menu bar included, but this doesn't exist.

I also saw nearly every post related to this issue, but couldn't get wiser. I would like to know where I have to look for solving this issue.

The docs say "There should now be a CiviCRM link in your WordPress menu. Click that link and the CiviCRM Menu, Shortcuts, Search and New Individual Blocks should appear" but it is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress doesn't have a concept of "access to CiviCRM from the front end, as I did under Drupal". You access the CiviCRM admin UI via the WordPress admin UI. That's it.

The "base page" that you see which has "Do not delete this page. Page content is generated by CiviCRM" as its content is used for displaying CiviCRM forms, profiles, events etc on the front-end. You will find links scattered throughout the CiviCRM admin UI that will point you there. It uses WordPress Rewrite Rules to tease out what to show, so, for example:

https://yourdomain.tld/civicrm/event/info/?reset=1&id=2

will show a CiviCRM Event.

Comment: If this is true, it is a little bit disappointing: all the members of the staff who manage the file of subscriptors needs to log in into the backend?

Comment: not sure i understand, but yes WP users with the right permissions should get access to civicrm backend

Comment: @petednz-fuzion: I want some users of CiviCRM to access CiviCRM backend, but *not* the backend of Wordpress.

Comment: Why does the docs say "There should now be a CiviCRM link in your WordPress menu. Click that link and the CiviCRM Menu, Shortcuts, Search and New Individual Blocks should appear"? See https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/wordpress/

Comment: The permissions that you grant the users will determine what parts of the WordPress back-end they see.

Comment: The "CiviCRM link in your WordPress menu" refers to the WordPress admin menu.